# React Native Unresponsive on Launch

Tags: ios, react-native

We have a react native app that is incredibly slow from the time it launches until it allows you to tap anything on the screen. We make a few network requests and such but they are all async. I have been trying to debug this for a while with no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is truly going out on a limb because your post unfortunately lacks much information to go off of, but it appears from your gif that you're not able to click on it until after that loading spinner goes away.

Is it positioned on top of everything else, capturing the touch events and preventing them from actually landing on their targets?

If so, you may want to do something like this to prevent that from happening:

```
<View pointerEvents="none">
    ...
</View>
```

Comment: On closer inspection, looks like the click lands and then after some wait ultimately navigates.  I'll leave the answer even though I suspect strongly it's not right. :)

Comment: Yea, unfortunately our code would take a while to get through to find the chunks important, but I tried removing all of the network requests, dispatch's, and even the refreshing code on the `ListView`. It isn't limited to the listview either, you can't touch anything until the refresh is done.